# GnuTLS cant call hashing functions

Tags: hash, cryptography, gnutls

after compiling and testing some functions available in the gnuTLS library I am having problems using the crypto library.
When I try to generate a hash using

```
gnutls_hash_hd_t *dig;
gnutls_hash_init (dig, GNUTLS_DIG_SHA1);
```

for then calculate a hash using

```
 gnutls_hash (dig, const void * ptext, size_t ptext_len);
```

my problen appears when

```
gnutls_hash_init (dig, GNUTLS_DIG_SHA1);
```

calls gnutls_malloc() inside crypto-api.c givng me a segfault.
I dont know what and doing wrong and gnuTLS API is not very begginer friendly, any kind of suggestions and advices are welcome

Answer (score 0):

The function `gnutls_hash_init` does not allocate the memory for the `gnutls_hash_hd_t`. Rather, it expects a pointer to an existing allocation.

So the correct usage would be e.g.

```
  gnutls_hash_hd_t dig = {0}; // zero-initialize
  gnutls_hash_init(&dig, GNUTLS_DIG_SHA1);
```